# interpreting and reading any file type in c#

Tags: c#

I have opened a file in Notepad++ and it looks like the attached image. What do these symbols represent? Hex/Ascii/Binary? I would like to read and write to a separate file. I used StreamReader and StreamWriter and read write character by character but the resultant file has symbols which are different than the input file.

Since the file size is massive, I would like to use stream.
[image]

Comment: Well what was the input file? If it wasn't a text file - or wasn't in the encoding you were reading it with - then this garbage would indeed be the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is binary data, it can mean anything. Without knowing, it is just a series of bytes, where a byte is an 8-bit number. It can be *represented* as characters (in any number of encodings), as hexadecimal numbers or even a punch card.

If you want to read/write binary data, then FileStream is your friend. StreamReader/Writer is character oriented. Characters used to be equivalent to bytes in the good old days when there was ASCII encoding only, but this isn't the case anymore. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to copy the exact binary data, without caring whether it's text or not, you should be using `Stream`. For example:

```
using (var input = Stream.OpenRead(inputFile))
using (var output = Stream.OpenWrite(outputFile))
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}
```

When you use `StreamWriter`, you're interpreting the data as *text* data in a particular encoding - and if it's not text, or it's not in that encoding, then you'll end up with garbage, basically.